# Enable/Disable is NOT working for Grid button

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In the Invoices screen, I have a new customized field on the Header and also added a new button on the Document Details tab above the grid.

Based on the Customized field condition we need to enable and disable the button. I have added this button as a toolbar button and added enable/disable conditions in ARInvoices row selected event but it is NOT working as expected. Can you please provide your thoughts on this?

Please find the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you set the CommitChanges = True on the new customized field?

Comment: @Kulvir Yes, I have added CommintChanges = "true", still getting this issue

Comment: Have you set the `dependsOnGrid` property of the button?  I've found this to affect functionality greatly.

Comment: @beardedmogul, beat me to the dependsOnGrid answer. Not certain its going to help but I know if affects the behavior when you have an empty grid or not. if that does not help I would look at how the ADD ORDER button is defined for any clues as that seems to be the behavior you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen, I have found a section of the Framework documentation that has some description of what you are trying to accomplish. let me know if this helps?
https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=a0f8f9e9-7997-4325-bc69-b58039dd3699
So based on this it sounds link you need to "un-set" a DependsOnGrid as that is what is used to get the button to an inactive state when the grid is empty. It sounds like you are looking for the opposite.